# Ubuntu 12.04 - gnome-settings-daemon crash and problem with fn keys

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, brightness, samsung

I know there are many questions similar to this, I've been reading them and searching for a solution for 2 days but no luck so far.

I have a Samsung NP550P5C laptop and just installed Ubuntu `12.04.3` on it. When I first installed there was nothing wrong, all the function keys, like brightness and volume adjustment, were working perfectly fine. Then I ran the updates including the kernel update. And suddenly my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys stopped working, even before I rebooted. I spent a couple of hours trying to solve it but it didn't work. So I did a fresh install again. I read somewhere that it could be the kernel update that causing it, so this time I didn't do the kernel update. It was ok this time until I rebooted after the updates, but after the reboot they again stopped working.
Only the touch pad enable/disable and screenshot keys are working now.

I tried installing `samsung-tools`, `samsung-laptop`, nothing changed.
Also when I go in to `System Settings`->`Keyboard`->`Shortcuts` and edit a shortcut, actually it recognizes the key, for example when I hit <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> it shows as "Audio raise volume".

Plus, when this problem with the function keys occurs, there's always a slight change in the graphics, like in firefox and vlc player the buttons are more edgy than before. It looks like something messed with the themes or something.

Thanks in advance

edit: When I run `gnome-settings-daemon` it returns the output below and crashes.

```
=== xinerama setup Configuration ===
  Clone: false
  Output: Laptop attached to LVDS-0
     status: on
     width: 1600
     height: 900
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DisplayPort-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
=== Applying Configuration Configuration ===
  Clone: false
  Output: Laptop attached to LVDS-0
     status: on
     width: 1600
     height: 900
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DisplayPort-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1

(gnome-settings-daemon:2955): Gdk-WARNING **: The program 'gnome-settings-daemon' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
  (Details: serial 274 error_code 8 request_code 140 minor_code 30)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Additional commands and outputs:

`sudo uname -u`

`Linux yunus-550P5C-550P7C 3.8.0-31-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 11 18:21:16 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`sudo lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

`sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel`

`ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring         2:2.21.6-0ubuntu4.1~precise1            X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver`

`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`

`/usr/sbin/lightdm`

`sudo apt-get install lightdm`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lightdm is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  xbindkeys thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Execute these commands once, hope it'll work after that: 1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}'|grep "^xserver"|tr '\n' ' ')` 2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` **this command would take some time to execute, depends on packages you've installed, so wait**. 3. `sudo update-initramfs -u` and then restart your system. I recommend you to copy and paste the commands in terminal. Reply what happens..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I executed the commands by copy&pasting but the result is still the same.

Comment: Did you get any error in any of the commands? Edit your question and post the output of following commands: `sudo uname -a`, `sudo  lsb_release -a` and `sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel` Reply..

Comment: There wasn't any error, everything seemed to went smoothly.

Comment: Pretty strange! You are using best compatible kernel `3.8.x`, latest LTS version of `12.04`, latest drivers for your devices and so on.. It should not show any errors.. :( Last thing I can suggest you to execute this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and chose `lightdm`->`ok` and `sudo update-grub` and restart your system. Reply..

Comment: Yes it's really weird. It may sound silly but what exactly do you mean by "chose `lightdm` -> `ok`" ?

Comment: When you'll execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` one list will be opened that will prompt to chose which `display manager` you want to use, since you don't have any other display manager, it will list `lightdm` on the list. Basically this command ****reconfigures** `lightdm`(display manager) and removes any errors related to it. You have to press `tab` button in order to highlight `ok` then press `enter` to close it.. Don't forget to restart your system. Reply..

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` executes silently, without opening any list, is it normal?

Comment: No it's not normal!! How is it possible that you'll not get any thing? The list will be opened in the same terminal not any where else.. Run this command and tell me what is the output : `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` and `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

Comment: I updated the question and wrote the outputs there.

Comment: It is clear that your default display manager is `lightdm`. Since you are not able to configure it, there is some problem in `lightdm`. I suggest you to install another display manager and check whether you'll be able to solve your issure or not. Just give me 2 minutes, to post my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Method**

**Try to reconfigure lightdm** (if it doesn't solve your issue then go for *2nd* Method)

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list.

[image: lighdm]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1378375_454948661291695_937916838_n.jpg))</sub>

- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow *2nd Method*.

**2nd Method**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like **lightdm**):

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `gdm` from the list:

[image: gdm]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1390653_454948664625028_2140985254_n.jpg))</sub>

```
    sudo reboot now
```

- If it's still not fixed, try removing `lightdm` after installing `gdm`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm
  sudo reboot
  ```

Hope these methods solve your issue. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: Thank you again. I don't get it, I tried several display managers: `gdm`, `slim`, `xdm`, none of them seem to work. When I boot I get black screen instead of the login screen.

Comment: When your system start in black screen press `ctrl+alt+f1` and login. Then execute this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a && sudo update-grub` then restart your system: `sudo reboot`. If it still doesn't help you then try this post once: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). I'm really sorry, I couldn't help you..

Comment: It didn't work either, but `gdm` started to work just fine after removing `lightdm` completely by `sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm`. So you actually helped me, thanks!

Comment: I was obsessed with this issue, and did one last fresh ubuntu install to detect which update is causing it. So I applied all the updates one by one and I finally figured the cause of this problem.
`gnome-settings-daemon` updated from version `3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6.2` to `3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6.3` and that's when the display manager went crazy. I manually downgraded it, so everything's perfect again.

Comment: If your problem is solved after installing `gdm`, I insist you to mark this question as solved.. To do that you have to `accept` my answer. I also prefer you to edit my answer and do the possible change (if any) so that it will help others to get their problem solved.. :)